# How to know if a parent process is waiting for a child process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, posix

In Linux given two processes with known `pIds`, and one being the parent of the other,

is it possible to know if the parent is waiting for the child process to finish?

Thanks

Comment: look at the sourcecode

Comment: i'am afraid it's the only way

Comment: this might be helpfull a bit -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801604/how-do-i-tell-what-a-linux-process-is-waiting-for

Answer (score 4):

Check the parent's kernel stack and/or wchan ("wait channel")

```
$ ps -o pid,stat,wchan:24,command 1978243
    PID STAT WCHAN                    COMMAND
1978243 Ss   wait                     bash

$ cat /proc/1978243/wchan 
do_wait

$ sudo cat /proc/1978243/stack 
[<ffffffff8108008d>] do_wait+0x1cd/0x260
[<ffffffff810812ab>] SyS_wait4+0x7b/0xf0
[<ffffffff815f7cf2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa4
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

This shows whether the process is inside a kernel syscall – if it shows the `wait` syscall, that's the most common way of waiting for a child process.

Note that many event-based processes *do not* use the `wait()` call for a long time – instead they wait on `poll()` instead, until some event is received (which may or may not be a SIGCHLD event).

Therefore this only works with simple linear processes. For everything else, you would have to check the source code or such.

Comment: thanks @grawity, that's really useful, I can see that the two first commands lead to the waiting stack instruction, but how to be sure it is wating for the child process and not any other event?

Comment: @idelvall: If it has called `wait()`, then it's waiting for a child process, because that's the only thing the `wait()` syscall _does_. [As opposed to e.g. `poll()` which would wait for arbitrary events on fds.]

Comment: what if the parent has created several child processes?